# How can I combine the PyDev unit test runner with Web2py?

Tags: pydev, web2py

I'm using Eclipse/PyDev on a Web2py application, and I'd like to create a launch configuration that runs a unit test using web2py.

Normally, Web2py wants you to run a unit test with a test runner script, [like so](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1392/unit-testing):

```
python web2py.py -S testa -M -R testRunner.py
```

testRunner.py includes a main method that runs:

```
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

However, in PyDev, the test running is managed outside of your source, in `pysrc\runfiles.py`.

PyDev's [test runner](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html) doesn't even take -S, -M, and -R as arguments, and it has no way of passing them on to web2py.py, which it expects to be a suite of tests, and not a runner.

Is there a way to test Web2py using a PyDev unittest configuration, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion in this case is using the pytest runner (configure it in the pyunit preferences)... I haven't searched, but I bet there's some plugin for running web2py with pytest.